# Display a TODO keyword on agenda but hide it in Todo list

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs, gtd

I am following `Getting Things Done (GTD)` with `org-mode`, and this is my current TODO setup:

`#+TODO: TODO(t) PROJECT(p) | WAITING(w@/!) DONE(d!) CANCELLED(c@)`

I want to display entries with PROJECT keyword appear on agenda but hide those entries from the todo list. The rationale behind this setup is that while PROJECT entries are not actionable and therefore should not appear on the TODO list, they will have deadlines that need to be shown on the agenda.

The main problem is that, if I let it remain active, then it appears both on agenda and todo list. On the other hand, if I change it to inactive, then it disappears on both todo list and agenda. What setting do I need in order to display PROJECT entries on just agenda, but not on the todo list?

EDIT:

[This album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqxi5.jpg) clarifies what I am trying to say. To explain further, the first image describes the demo setup. The second and the third images are todo list and agenda when PROJECT keyword is active. The fourth and the fifth images are todo list and agenda when PROJECT keyword is inactive.

What I want to achieve is third and fourth images where PROJECT entry is displayed when deadline is set, but it doesn't appear on the todo list.

Comment: The master todo list is a complete flat text file, whereas the agenda buffer is just select portions of text that have been copied from the master todo list.  Are you asking how to hide select potions of the master todo list?  If so, then check out the section in the manual about creating an org sparse-tree:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Sparse-trees.html

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I added some images and more explanations to clarify what I meant. Let me know if my wording is still confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a prefix ARG to specifically select your TODO items only (then you still keep the possibility to show projects also in your todo list):

```
C-u AGENDA-HOTKEY t TODO RET
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a really easy solution. I don't know why I didn't think about that. I've set `org-agenda-custom-commands` to have `("t" "Todo List" todo "TODO")`